# Update button using ajax and data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to make an update function instead of using forms, I use data-* attribute and ajax. I just want to prevent the button from firing after I update the values but I have a problem with my script after updating the button shouldn't be firing because the value of the input(number) and the data-* attribute of my button are already the same. I hope you can help me guys. Thanks in advance :)

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn-edituser', function(){
var button = $(this);
var upval = button.parent().prev().find('.data-avail').val();//get the value of the input(number)
var updateId = button.data('updateid');// this is the user id to be pass on to the php file
var tempAv = button.data('tempavail'); //doesn't get the new values after updating this is my PROBLEM

if(upval != tempAv){ //check if the input(number) has been changes value / doesn't have the same value with the data attribute (temporary)
    button.addClass('disabled');
    button.html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Updating...');

    $.ajax({
        url:'./inc/update-avail.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{upval:upval, updateId:updateId},
        success:function(data){             
            button.removeClass('disabled');
            button.attr('data-tempavail', upval); //update the data attribute (temporary)
            button.removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-success').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Success');
            setTimeout(function(){                  
                button.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-info').html('<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit');
            }, 1000);
        }           
    });
}   });
```

Comment: change button.attr('data-tempavail', upval); to button.attr('data-tempavail', tempAv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `success:` handler try to set data via `$.data` instead of `$.attr` as later one will stores the information directly on the element in attributes.
So code should be like:

```
success:function(data){             
    button.removeClass('disabled');
    button.data('tempavail', upval); //update the data which can be seen via button.data('tempavail') again on next button click
    button.removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-success').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Success');
    setTimeout(function(){                  
        button.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-info').html('<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I have another problem but it's out of the topic can you help me?

Comment: @johnnyblade - sure. please go ahead. or create separate question and post me the link for it

Comment: maybe I can ask you here because I cannot post another question so here it is. I always get this "Uncaught TypeError: button2.parents(...).remove(...).draw is not a function(…)" but it works just fine. I just don't want to see this type of error in my console this is my code

Comment: $('body').on('click', '.btn-deleteuser', function() { 
 var button = $(this); 
 var deleteId = button.data('deleteid'); 
 var button2 = $('table button.data'+deleteId);  
 
 button.addClass('disabled');
 button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 button.html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Deleting...');
 
 $.ajax({
  url:'./inc/delete-user.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data:{deleteId:deleteId},
  success:function(data){
   button.html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Success!');
   button.next('.btn-danger').text('Close');
   button2.parents('tr').remove().draw(false);   
}});});

Comment: which jquery plugin you are using? what is `.draw()` function?

Comment: I'm using DataTable, I also don't have any idea of the .draw() function. I just copied it on their website. Because I wanted to do is after I delete the user in database the row in the table will also be deleted

Comment: My God, I'm such a newbie. it's ok if I remove the .draw() function it works well

Comment: but i guess if your remove call to `.draw()` then your DataTable may not get refreshed.